# Issue with jquery , missing ; before statement

Tags: php, jquery

Following piece of code works in my localhost, but when i upload files in my server behaves very strange.

```
$(function(){
var myPath=<?= BASE_URL ?>+'myaddress/mystatelist';
$('#country').val('US')
loadMystate('US',myPath);
});
```

Actually I created vhost in my localhost like "test.study.com/projectname" which means "`<?= BASE_URL ?>`" will takes "`/projectname`" as a BASE_URL. Facing issue when i upload files under the BASE_URL "`http://dev.study.com`". Now i am getting error in firebug as "`missing ; before statement  var myPath=http://dev.study.com/+'myaddress/mystatelist';` "

What I done wrong this code? Kindly help me.

Comment: What does the actual generated javascript code look like after PHP has processed it?

Comment: If you don't understand why some JS isn't working — show us the **JavaScript**. Don't show us some PHP that will generate some JS when it is executed.

Comment: It'd be a pretty crappy mechanic who wouldn't work on your car because you thought something was wrong with the differential when the problem was really with the suspension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotes around the base URL so it's trying to interpret it as code.  Try:

```
var myPath = '<?= BASE_URL ?>myaddress/mystatelist';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JS code looks like this :

```
var myPath=http://dev.study.com/+'myaddress/mystatelist';
```

**Your are missing quotes arround the first string** :

```
var myPath='http://dev.study.com/'+'myaddress/mystatelist';
```

And, to get those quotes generated from PHP, your PHP code should probably look like this :

```
var myPath = '<?= BASE_URL ?>' + 'myaddress/mystatelist';
```

Or your could remove the strings concatenation, and directly use :

```
var myPath = '<?= BASE_URL ?>myaddress/mystatelist';
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings have to be quoted in JavaScript.

```
var myPath=http://dev.study.com/
```

Where are the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

`var myPath='<?= BASE_URL ?>myaddress/mystatelist';`

Your PHP code is written to the output, but it was not inside a string. Your value would have thrown an invalid RegEx error in JS.

Also, `$('#country').val('US')` - are you sure that's doing anything and it does appear to be missing a `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the short tag `<?=` may not be supported on your server. There's a good answer about this at  [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use).

On second thought, that's probably not the issue as the variable is printing - sorry!